# Is it possible for a map to have two maps as a key and value in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, stl

Hi I'm trying to have a map of a sort like map<map<string,string>,map<int,int>>. Is it possible to have such a map in C++..? Or is the concept incorrect..? Using this method to have something like a cricket players status - name, designation, runs and wickets. The code I've pasted is something I tried, it's incorrect.

```
map<map<string,string>,map<int,int>> m;
    map<map<string,string>,map<int,int>>::iterator itr;
    map<int,int>::iterator ptr;
    m.insert(make_pair("string1","string2"),map<int,int>());
    m["string1"].insert(make_pair(10,20));
    
    for(itr = m.begin();itr!=m.end();itr++) {
        for (ptr = itr->second.begin(); ptr != itr->second.end(); ptr++) {
            cout << "First key is " << itr->first<< " And second key is " << ptr->first<< " And value is " << ptr->second << endl;
        }
    }
```

All feedback is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `m["string1"]` couldn't be valid - you said you wanted the key to be a `map<string,string>`. I don't understand why you'd want a map as a key. Given your description, looks like you'd be better off with a map with string keys and CricketPlayer values, with the key being the player name and CricketPlayer storing whatever stats you need, or something to that effect.

Comment: A `std::map` requires the key to be orderable using a strict-weak-order.  Having a `std::map` as a key does not meet those requirements.  Also, think of real life -- when you look up some player on the Internet, what do you type into the search engine?  The player's name, right?  The name would be the key, thus a `std::string` as the key makes more sense.  The `data` would be the results for that search.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie std::map values can be compared with `<`, does this fail strict weak ordering?

Comment: Looks like your concept here is incorrect. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve? How should data structure work?

Comment: A map as a key to another map can be technically valid, but it rarely makes any sense. What functionality do you want to implement with it?

Comment: @Sorin I mean values *of type* std::map, not values *stored in* std::map. `std::less<std::map<string,string>>` is perfectly well defined.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. You are right: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_cmp

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. OK, I didn't know this.  It makes sense for `std::map` to have `==` and `!=`, but `<` didn't make sense to me.  Wait...Hey, those operators have been removed in C++20!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `Wait...Hey, those operators have been removed in C++20!` Those operators have been removed from all (I assume; maybe there are exceptions) standard types in C++20 since they are generated from the `<=>` operator instead.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible for a map to have two maps as a key and value in C++?

Yes, it is. There aren't many restrictions on the value type. Primary restriction on the key is that it must be orderable by the provided comparator (`std::less<Key>` by default). `std::map` does satisfy those requirements given appropriate key and value types.

> ```
> m.insert(make_pair("string1","string2"),map<int,int>());
> ```

This isn't correct. You cannot pass the value as a separate argument to `insert`. Furthermore you cannot initialise the key that is a map using a pair. Here is a correct example:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> key {
    {"string1", "string2"},
};
// not needed since operator[] will insert a value initialised element
// m.emplace(key, std::map<int,int>{});
```

> ```
> m["string1"].insert(make_pair(10, 20));
> ```

This isn't correct. The key of the map is another map, and a string cannot be compared to a map, so this lookup cannot work. In this corrected example:

```
m[key].emplace(10, 20);
```

> ```
> cout << "First key is " << itr->first<< " And second key is " << ptr->first<< " And value is " << ptr->second << endl;
> ```

This won't work since you cannot insert a map (that is the key) into a character stream. You could write something like this for example:

```
for (auto& [key, value] : m) {
    std::cout << "key: ";
    for (auto& [key_key, key_value] : key) {
        std::cout
            << "key of key is " << key_key
            << " value of key is " << key_value
            << ", "
        ;
    }
    std::cout << "\nvalue: ";
    for (auto& [value_key, value_value] : value) {
        std::cout
            << "key of value is " << value_key
            << " value of value " << value_value
             << ", "
        ;
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n";
}
```

---

However, it's quite rare for map to be a useful key of a map, and considering your mistaken use of your map, I suspect that you actually need the key to be a string rather than a map.